# How to generalize integration by substitution to a rule about inner products?

Tags: calculus

Is there a way to generalize [integration by substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution) to a rule about inner products?

Let $D$ be the derivative operator. Let $g'$ be $x \mapsto (Dg)(x)$.

Integration by substitution can be expressed as follows.

$$ \int_{g(a)}^{g(b)} f(x) dx = \int_a^b g'(x) \cdot f(g(x)) dx $$

This makes intuitive sense, we are transforming the input to $f$ using $g$ and thus we need to scale the output by a correction factor, $g'(x)$.

If we assume that $a \le b$ and let $I : \mathbb{R} \to \{0, 1\}$ be the indicator function for $[a, b]$, then we can express the above as follows (assuming $g$ is monotonic increasing or monotonic decreasing along $I^{-1}(1)$).

$$ \int_\mathbb{R} I(g(x)) \cdot f(x) dx = \int_\mathbb{R} I(x) \cdot g'(x) \cdot f(g(x)) d x $$

To me, at least, this looks a lot like an inner product, rewriting it more suggestively gives us the following. **I have reason to believe that the rule below is wrong/incomplete.**

$$ \langle I \circ g, f \rangle = \langle g'I, f \circ g\rangle $$

However, I don't think that this generalizes from set indicator functions like $I$ to more general functions. If we assume that it does and apply the rule *twice*, we're left with a kind of silly conclusion.

$$ \langle I \circ g, f \rangle \\
   \langle g'I, f \circ g \rangle \\
   \langle f \circ g, g'I \rangle \\
   \langle g'f, g' \cdot I \circ g \rangle $$

I don't think it holds in general that I can simply rescale both factors by $g'$ for an arbitrary choice of $g$.

Comment: What you are looking for is called change of variables for functions with several variables. You can check it at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution), for instance.